# Find a fitting function for a strongly monotonically falling function

Tags: fitting, data

I would like to find a fit for the following data set. The problem is that I could not find a suitable first guess function. does anyone have an idea?

The problem is that it goes down very sharply and I could not create the same curve.

```
    {{0.01, 4852.3349596878925`}, {1.01, 1.2599309595978265`}, {2.01, 
      0.36014024535778794`}, {3.01, 0.17207484559273448`}, {4.01, 
      0.10163995857129492`}, {5.01, 0.06746942554187932`}, {6.01, 
      0.0482299984817708`}, {7.01, 0.03628947526788853`}, {8.01, 
      0.02835077400112903`}, {9.01, 0.02279480434554853`}, {10.01, 
      0.018748705672517164`}, {11.01, 0.015707177059230484`},{12.01, 
       0.01336077499094743`}, {13.01, 0.011511157790446497`}, {14.01, 
      0.010026306601459237`}, {15.01, 0.008815511518914671`}, {16.01, 
      0.0078147322585504`}, {17.01, 0.006977685118128205`}, {18.01, 
      0.006270228333478312`}, {19.01, 0.005666719059798636`}, {20.01, 
      0.005147587416409233`}, {21.01, 0.004697683421085946`}, {22.01, 
      0.004305127270666992`}, {23.01, 0.003960494468141799`}, {24.01, 
      0.003656229467465407`}, {25.01, 0.003386216178768524`}, {26.01, 
      0.0031454601639417804`}, {27.01, 0.0029298495146010263`}, {28.01, 
      0.0027359737547190174`}, {29.01, 0.0025609843062064166`}, {30.01, 
      0.00240248668044179`}, {31.01, 0.0022584560616233772`}, {32.01, 
      0.0021271705366875666`}, {33.01, 0.002007158252643869`}, {34.01, 
      0.001897154987118916`}, {36.01, 0.0017960691782843285`},
 {37.01, 0.0017029560273967542`},
 {38.01,0.001616990988445198`}, {39.01, 0.0015374584790530652`}, {40.01, 
      0.0014637198715602706`}, {41.01, 0.001395241443372967`}, {42.01, 
      0.0013314846251077327`}, {43.01, 0.0012721165255491554`}, {44.01, 
      0.0012165807482059767`}, {45.01, 0.001164755760056921`}, {46.01, 
      0.0011161820139491026`}, {47.01, 0.001070431400159623`}, {48.01, 
      0.0010279630573571746`}, {49.01, 0.0009873843535750113`}, {50.01, 
      0.0009493705185392757`}, {51.01, 0.0009143827366463803`}, {52.01, 
      0.0008796811656744432`}, {53.01, 0.0008477772604310624`}, {54.01, 
      0.000819219690992591`}, {55.01, 0.0007889384800724267`}, {56.01, 
      0.0007609966333295045`}, {57.01, 0.0007386307607102363`}, {58.01, 
      0.0007130569324854982`}, {59.01, 0.0006857327239738379`}, {60.01, 
      0.0006675609429466444`}, {61.01, 0.0006507323939971138`}, {62.01, 
      0.0006236233530992878`}, {63.01, 0.0006003867944843993`}, {64.01, 
      0.0005933915130617356`}, {65.01, 0.000581054349074332`}, {66.01, 
      0.000545823851092829`}, {67.01, 0.0005196603243307006`}, {68.01, 
      0.0005483409010070409`}, {69.01, 0.0006229744287720763`}, {70.01, 
      0.0006829808542831213`}, {71.01, 0.0006851296140363589`}, {72.01, 
      0.0006440326026124424`}, {73.010, .0006021943328499655`}, {74.01, 
      0.0005809957768517377`}, {75, 0.0005705457897247148`}}
```

My first guess

```
lm = NonlinearModelFit[Data, 
  a Exp[b (1 - 1 (28/t)^(4/5))] + c*(t/((d)^f + t^f)), {a, b, c, d, 
   f}, t]
```

[image]

and this is the same data that I tried to fit in Python, but the result was terrible
[image]

Comment: Please post the function in Mathematica code.

Comment: @cvgmt I haven't really found a usable first cast to post here, but I'll post some Matheamtica code as soon as I can.

Comment: On a log-log plot the data is on a straight line. So probably try a power-law curve, y=c[1]*x^c[2].

Comment: There are two typos in your posted data.  (1) There is a missing comma in `{11.01, 0.015707177059230484} {12.01, 0.01336077499094743}` and (2) There is a missing comma in `{37.01, 0.0017029560273967542} {38.01, 0.001616990988445198}`.  This results in the two extreme points `{132.23, 0.00020986}` and `{{1406.75, 2.75366*10^-6}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the useful hint in @H.Zhou's comment try

```
logdata = Map[Log, data(* you data*)] ;
fit = NonlinearModelFit[logdata, {b - a logx },{a, b }, logx]

Exp[b - a Log[x]]/.fit["BestFitParameters"]
(*1.18047/x^1.8089*)

Show[{Plot[Exp[b - a Log[x]] /.fit["BestFitParameters"], {x, 0, 140}],ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: [`ListLogLogPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLogPlot.html) and [`LogLogPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) are probably more appropriate here because they give a better intuition on the relative size of the mismatch (as the fit is done in log-log space with uniform weights).

Comment: Although it makes little difference in the fit, the OP has two errors in the posted data.  The two values greater than 75 are due to missing commas in the posted data.

Comment: Thanks a lot and thank you all

Answer (score 5):

The OP says

> The problem is that I could not find a suitable first guess function

One option is to leave the guesswork to *Mathematica* and use [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
data=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ufB1Wpyi","TSV"];
f=FindFormula[data];
```

Now `f[x]` is

[image]

Perhaps the options like [`PerformanceGoal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)`->"Quality"`, [`SpecificityGoal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpecificityGoal.html)`-> "High"` and [`TimeConstraint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstraint.html)`-> 60` could help to get a more reliable answer.

```
FindFormula[data
    , x
    , 3
    , All
    , SpecificityGoal -> "High"
    , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
    , TimeConstraint  -> 60
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my tip: when exploring trends like these, use different ways to plot the data to get a good idea of what you're dealing with. For example:

```
ListLogPlot[data]
ListLogLogPlot[data]
```

[image]

The fact that you get a nearly straight line in the log-log plot suggests that you're dealing with a power law of the form `y == a x^r`. However, you can also see a bump on the right side of the plot that cannot be captured that easily. I'll leave that up to you to deal with.

As a rule of thumb: always try to find a plot that makes your data linear (at least in a certain region of the plot), if you can. It's extremely easy to detect linear trends visually. But seeing the difference between an exponential or power law, or a log and a power law is basically impossible.

In addition: data that varies over orders of magnitude like this dataset cannot be fitted reliably with `NonLinearModelFit` without thinking it through! The data goes from more than 4000 to less than 0.001; it varies over 7 orders of magnitude! For all intends and purposes, `NonLinearModelFit` is going to treat most of the values as zeros because of this. When there's a 4000 in your dataset, it won't care too much about the difference between 0.1 and 0.001.

Comment: All very good points (+1) ! Histograms and fits are dangerous, mainly because people use them blindly.